# How to pass runtime value to constructor parameter when register a type?

Tags: c#, unity-container

Background:

I have a lot of classes named XxxService where one of the constructor parameter is UserId, like

```
public XxxService: IXxxService
{
     public XxxService(string userId, IMmmService mmm, INnnService nnn) {....}
}
```

The userId is coming from HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.
The number of the service class is huge so I don't want to create an IIdProvider interface for each service class.

I know that I can pass a compile time value to the constructor when registration.

```
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>
    (new InjectionConstructor(5,                      //<-- compile time value
             container.Resolve<IMmmService>(), 
             container.Resolve<INnnService>()));
```

How can I pass function to the constructor? Something like:

```
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>
    (new InjectionConstructor( ()=>GetIdFromRequest(),  //<--- runtime value
             container.Resolve<IMmmService>(), 
             container.Resolve<INnnService>() ))
```

I also know there is a InjectionFactory

```
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>
     (new InjectionFactory( 
          (x)=> new Service( 
             GetIdFromRequest(), 
             container.Resolve<IMmmService>(), 
             container.Resolve<INnnService>()))
```

But this needs to resolve other parameters manually.

Is there any better way to do it? I just want to pass the runtime value to one of the parameters by index of name, and other parameters should be handled by the container automatically.

So the most thing I want is something like:

```
// fake code
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>
    (new InjectedParameter( 0,       // the first parameter 
             ()=>GetIdFromRequest()  // <--- runtime value
             )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the `InjectionFactory` method, use a `Resolve` method overload that allows you to specify a `ResolverOverride`, specifically a `ParameterOverride`, and pass the runtime value in that way. To avoid a `StackOverflowException`, you can use an additional named registration with compile-time values provided for the relevant parameters, like this:

```
class A
{
    public A(int id, B b, C c)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Got " + id);
    }
}

class B { }

class C { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var unity = new UnityContainer())
    {
        unity.RegisterType<A>(
            "compile-time", 
            new InjectionConstructor(-1, 
                new ResolvedParameter<B>(), 
                new ResolvedParameter<C>()
                )
        );
        unity.RegisterType<A>(
            new InjectionFactory(
            u => u.Resolve<A>("compile-time", 
                new ParameterOverride("id", new Random().Next()))
            )
        );
        unity.Resolve<A>();
        unity.Resolve<A>();
        unity.Resolve<A>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, it's not so obvious after all. I'll add a full example.

Comment: container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(  new InjectionFactory(c=>c.Resolve<IService>(new ParameterOverride("Userd", GetIdFromRequest())))); throws an StackoverflowException.

Comment: container.RegisterType<IService>( new InjectionFactory(c=>c.Resolve<Service>(new ParameterOverride("Userd", GetIdFromRequest())))) is good!

Comment: Many thanks! Really helps and saved me a lot of time.

Comment: what is `"compile-time"` string?

Answer (score 0):

I see no actual problem with your InjectionFactory approach.

But the entire concept of having a service which keeps user name as part of it's state seems wrong to me.

But you'd better go with implementing the user parameter as a service, and inject that, to make it clear that it works that way, instead making it a part of service object lifecycle, which happens if you pass a value in Service class contrcutor.

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    string GetCurrentUserName();
}

public class CookieBasedAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
 /// ...
}
```

You can then drop the part of configuration code with InjectionConstructor entirely.

Comment: Not sure if you have seen my updated post. The value 1 should be a runtime value. Is it possible?

Comment: sorry i did not understand the question completely from the first time

Comment: Many thanks. However, the parameter 'UserId' is used in almost all service classes (a huge number). I don't want to change all of them.